# Is there a way to automatically save Slack messages to a Google sheet (without using a paid tool like Zapier)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, slack

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically save any new messages posted in a slack channel to a google sheet, like how you might send google sheet data to slack via webhook upon a specific event trigger, just in reverse (slack to google sheet)?

I tried the workflow builder for google sheets but it looks like that still requires intentional usage in order to send the information to the connected sheet, I'm looking for a way to just automatically save a typical slack message as soon as it's entered.